# User-defined type not defined for mscoree.CorRuntimeHost

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver, vba7, vba6

I am trying to automate edge without installing selenium using VBA but I am getting error while using the selenium wrapper code, did I miss anything on this code or do I need to add any settings in my Excel addin?

My code below:

```
   Function CreateObjectSelenium(strTypeName As String) As Object
   'Required references: Mscoree (taken from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscoree.tlb) and     mscorlib
        Static domain As mscorlib.AppDomain
        If domain Is Nothing Then
        Dim o As Object
        Set o = New mscoree.CorRuntimeHost
            With o
            .Start:
            .GetDefaultDomain domain
            End With
        End If
        Set CreateObjectSelenium = domain.CreateInstanceFrom(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\SeleniumBasic\Selenium.dll", strTypeName).Unwrap
    End Function

Sub esempio()
    Dim oEdge As Object 'Selenium.EdgeDriver
    Set oEdge = CreateObjectSelenium("Selenium.EdgeDriver")
    With oEdge
    .Start "edge"
    .Get "https://www.esempio.it"
    MsgBox "pausa"
    .Quit
   End With
End Sub`
```

I am trying to run this code but getting error of user-defined type not defined for mscorlib and mscoree.CorRuntimeHost